# How to use an integer variable for remove from a list in Python

Tags: python

I am making a small python program for an address book and I'm trying to create an edit feature.

```
def editEntry():
f = open("address_book.txt", "r")
editList = []
for line in f:
    Name, Age, Address, City = line.split(',')
    editList.append([Name, Age, Address, City])

print (editList , "\n")

choice = int(input("Which entry would you like to edit?" + "\n"))
test = editList[choice - 1]
del editList [choice]
print (test)

editEntryList = []

Name = input("What is the name?" + "\n")
Age = input("What is the age?" + "\n")
Address = input("What is the address?" + "\n")
City = input("What is the city?" + "\n")

editList.append(Name + ", ")
editList.append(Age + ", ")
editList.append(Address + ", ")
editList.append(City + "\n")

print(editList)
print(editEntryList)
```

I take in the data from a .txt file and you choose which entry you want to edit. I'm then trying to remove that one from the list so it can all be rewritten to the .txt file without having a duplicate entry.

From what I can find I need to use

```
del *List*[index]
```

but because I take in a number and store it in a variable I can't use the variable (choice) for the index.

How can I fix this?

**edit**

So in the .txt file I currently have 3 entries. The third of which needs editing.

The code I have already reads the 3 lines into the list so
Index 0 contains the first line
Index 1 contains the second line
Index 2 contains the third line

Once the user inputs which entry they want to edit I want that index removing from the list so it only contains 2 and then later on in the program I simply take in the details the user wants to readd and rewrite the 3 entries into the .txt file again.

Comment: Why exactly do you think `del editList[choice]` won't work?

Comment: it doesn't work because choice is a string and not an int I think but I can't figure out how to change it into an int?

Comment: *"choice is a string"*; given `choice = int(...)` I doubt it. Give a [mcve].

Comment: `del editList[int(choice)]`

Comment: Add to your question what you are expecting to happen and what is happening instead. Also, it looks like your indentation may be messed up. Make sure it is correct.

Comment: Which error are you getting? My guess right now is that your `editList` contains only one element which is a list itself, given `editList.append([Name, Age, Address, City])`. And you want this to be a list of 4 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use lower case for variable names: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Second, you should use the csv module to read and write csv files: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Third, you should print the number of the line:

```
for i, line in enumerate(editList, 1):
    print (i, line)
```

Fourth: `del` (or `pop`) will remove an element by index. This is what you want, but be sure to use `choice - 1` (credit to digitalLink).
With `pop`, you retrieve the entry and are able to modify only some values (e.g. if a value entered is empty, keep the current value) and put back the entry at the end of the list.

But note that you can modify `editList[choice-1]` in place: `editList[choice-1][0] = name`, ...

Fifth: you should not append to editList but to an editEntryList:

```
editEntryList = [name, age, address, city]
```

And then:

```
editList.append(editEntryList)
```

Sixth: I'm not sure a flat file is the best option. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite#module-sqlite3.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to subtract 1 from `choice`

```
del editList [choice - 1]
```